# Is it possible to see a wallet balance from a specific date?

Tags: transactions

I'm wanting to see a wallet balance on a specific date in the past, showing the amount of different tokens held within a Stellar network wallet. Like a retroactive snapshot of that wallet.

Is this possible to do somehow?

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible, but not off-the-shelf in Horizon. You'd either need to write some code that would start from the checkpoint before your target ledger number, and then replay the ledgers going forward. Or would start with the current balance, and replay the transactions in reverse.